# Strange DC point in vintage amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, dc

I've been restoring a vintage Marantz Model 33 amplifier and, for the most part, it came out ok, but I've noticed some weirdness in the final output stage of the center channel.

While it does work, I've noticed it went into clipping on the positive side of the sine wave on higher volumes. I then looked at voltages and noticed there's a DC voltage across C212.

I continued measuring voltages and noticed the junction of R226 and R227 was at +14V. It seems very strange and I thought Q206 was busted - replaced the BC559 with a 2N4402, but that didn't fix it.

It seems like a simple circuit, at least from the DC perspective, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it.

I've attached a section of the schematic, with annotations of the voltages I've measured in red.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I mean, it could be, but it's tied to a volume pot and I've done my measuring with volume at zero, so it wouldn't have any voltage to leak.

Comment: I would suspect Q205 as broken. Seems like Q206 is always open due to this.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, I'll try to replace it, I have enough spares.

Comment: Q205 and Q206 have to be working - the sim in my answer confirms the offset. Please provide a link to the schematic.

Comment: If you look in [this schematic](https://www.google.com/search?q=Marantz+Model+33+amplifier+schematic&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&oq=Marantz+Model+33+amplifier+schematic&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.4697j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#cobssid=s) there are errors - the minus 15 volts is called `15 volts` so, dig deep on this one.

Comment: What type is C212?  If these are paper, wax, or other suspect old cap types, replace them as they are probably leaky.

Comment: @Andyaka that's the schematic for the main preamp boards, but I don't see the error. It has both +15V (pad 5) and -15V (pad 22). Did you spot the error in a different place?

Comment: @rdtsc it's a new ceramic one, but I think there's nothing to leak there, it's a coupling cap on the input and it's tied to GND through R22.

Comment: [try this](https://www.vintageshifi.com/repertoire-pdf/pdf/telecharge.php?pdf=Marantz-33-Service-Manual.pdf) where I spotted the difference/anomaly - page 25 fig 13.

Comment: Ah, ok, I have a different version of the service manual (which has better scans, but missing pages). In mine it is clearly labeled -15V. I think the version you posted is missing the - due to scan quality or something (but I'm really enjoying the extra pages!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I simulate your circuit with no chance of capacitor leakage but not quite the same transistors, I get similarly offset values to your measurements: -

[image]

> *I continued measuring voltages and noticed the junction of R226 and
> R227 was at +14V. It seems very strange and I thought Q206 was busted*

This tells me that you haven't really established a close enough connection to the route cause when thinking that the +14 volts was *"very strange"*.

My answer doesn't help you find the root cause but, it does answer your question: your amplifier has an offset and, according to the circuit diagram you posted (and my simple simulation), it should have that same offset (within +/- a volt or so). However, that does seem at odds with what it should likely do so...

Dig deep and look for more information on the actual circuit. Web schematics are sometimes very flaky. It's all about getting good information right now.

Comment: Yes, I haven't established a close enough connection between the issue, but I'm asking because I don't know where to look next... parts seem ok (except Q205, I can try to replace that as well). Not sure I understand the part about the amplifier offset - at the junction of R226 and R227 voltage should be zero according to the schematic, so having +14V there seems like too much of a difference.

Comment: I would agree; on the face of it the junction of R226 and R227 makes sense being 0 volts so, I can only advise you that what I have simulated (despite matching your diagram) is not truly representative of the real circuit. Dig deep and looks at the schematic to see if you have missed something else @CatalinM

Comment: @CatalinM Yes, dig deeper: question that schematic. Perhaps resistor values are wrong. Calculating DC currents, red flags fly. Are you certain that R222=7.5K and R225=56 ?

Comment: @glen_geek that was a good idea. I had a look over the pictures of the board before I started working on it and while R222 and R225 did have those values, R224 seems to be 2k7 actually... which on my simulation lowers the DC voltage on the output considerably

Comment: @CatalinM While R224 affects the quiescent setpoint and therefore the open loop gain, the open loop gain is high enough that the exact value isn't important. Just the NFB, itself, which is about .333 when 1k and about .422 when 2.7k. Even if the open loop gain is as little as 1000 (it's probably much more), this means a stage gain from about 1.4 to about 2.0. And R224 sets this value. It's possible? (I don't know...) that there is a specification to meet and that R224 may have been used as a means to "calibrate" units against BJT and resistor part vagaries.

Comment: @CatalinM Temperature is already covered by the use of emitter degeneration for both BJTs. If their schematic is right, they've reserved out just enough voltage drop at the PNP emitter resistor to handle temperature variations reasonably well. Anyway, that may account for the difference between the schematic value and the actual value found in any particular shipped unit. I could just as easily be wrong about that, though. It's not marked on the schematic and I'd imagine they'd want to mark it somehow, if my guess is right. So... I'm just tossing it out there.

Comment: @jonk it wouldn't be impossible, although I highly doubt it is the case. An error seems way more likely once you look at the pair to the left and notice it has the same structure & same values, save for the R223/227 pair (which if I understand properly is there to set gain needed in this stage and not needed in the other)

Comment: @CatalinM are we all done here now? Is your question resolved?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see KVL design errors with noted voltages for Center Signal in the Marantz Schematic as shown. I have a fix also for you.

- Q1 does not draw much current  ~ 1/4 mA while if Q2 draws ~ 8mA that indicates a current ratio of 32.
- thus the voltage across R4 and R5 can NOT be equal as indicated by the Marantz voltages noted in black and is NOT equal by your measurements and Andy's sim.

Basically, the centre ch. is a non-inverting low-gain (Av~2) amplifier with 2 inverting stages but with negative feedback which is very **hfe** dependent and also sensitive to Q1 Vb input bias. It MUST go more negative since R4 voltage drop is about 1/hFE of the R5 drop.

**Suggested fix to balance the output near 0V is to pull down the base of Q1 to ~ -6V with 120k~ 150 k or so to -15V.**  This also attenuates the signal slightly.

### **Preferred fix** replace R4=100k with ~180k, add Rb= 360k from Q1-b to -15V

The other channels are done differently. But that's another answer.

Comment: I've just observed that R5 was 2k7 on the actual board (before my interventions). Put that through a sim and the output dc voltage drops to about 4.5V (from 14V)... not 0, but maybe low enough to prevent clipping on the positive sine.

Comment: That also reduces the gain propotionally. both my fixes are better